# Finding all fonts that contain a specific character

Tags: windows-7, fonts

There are tons of tools out there for listing all glyphs contained in a font.

I'm looking for the opposite: given a Unicode character, how can I find all installed fonts that contain it? Freeware preferred

Comment: interesting question, would like to know if there's such software (GUI or command line) for linux, because I'm curious about how application can render Chinese characters when I choosed a font which doesn't contains Chinese (for example, `ubuntu mono`).

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 I haven't tried, but it looks like *gucharmap* does it. For the record: *PopChar X* is an alternative for Mac (non-free).

Comment: As a last resort, you can always use http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.swf online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one: [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/software/babelmap.html)

Go to Font → Font Coverage

[image]