# How do you write superscripts in discord without latex?

Tags: discord

How do you write superscripts in discord without latex?

For example I know some discord channels have a bot that interprets latex and if you type `$3^2$` then the bot outputs an image of the big base number and the little exponent above.

But let's say I don't want an image.

I remember once seeing somebody write them, but i'm not sure how they did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of unicode.

If you open charmap and use the font Arial Unicode MS

[image]

So you see `0270` is the hex for superscript 0.

Funnily enough 1,2,3 are missing from that range. And If you click 4, you'll see 0274 is he hex for superscript 4.

The  1,2,3 are here

Some people type them easily 'cos they are on android phones and if you long press a digit then it goes superscript.

The rest are here 0,4,5,6,7,8,9 in superscript and subscript, and after the 9, it has superscript and subscript +,-,=,(,).

[image]

[image]

Babelmap shows clearly the unicode for each , in a tabular format that aligns the glyph with the equivalent hex.

[image]

Related- [Finding all fonts that contain a specific character](https://superuser.com/questions/564513/finding-all-fonts-that-contain-a-specific-character)

Babelmap shows that there's a number of fonts that support them

[image]

Also, if you see somebody type one of those superscripts, you can paste it into MS word and do ALT-X and see the unicode.